# how to queue Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect operations?

Tags: 2013

I want to upload images to sharepoint via client object model but the images are so big and I would like how to queue this uploads in an asp .net app to not break because of the delay of the upload of the images.

Example: I want to upload 5 images and then with their internal uri update some list items, but what happens if the second image is very big and it last so much, I got an exception or time exhaust and the what happens with the other uploads, I fail uploading only 1 of five files. How can I be sure to upload all the files?

Answer (score 0):

Queuing long operations like this in an ASP.NET application is a *bad idea*.

It can be done (SharePoint implemented the SPLongOperation) but there are examples of how to do it in the Patterns and Practices guidance.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650675.aspx

Comment: Thanks James, I know is not good but I don't know another way.